# При выборе checkbox и сохранении в базу пишется пустая строка (Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Небольшой проект на spring+thymeleaf, который пилится в учебных целях по урокам с ютуба (только там шаблонизатор freemarket, поэтому там спрашивать не вариант (замена произведена с целью самостоятельно параллельно разбираться)).

Напоролся на следующую проблему: 
При простановке checkbox на сайте и отправке, вместо отправки параметров в базу приходит пустая строка - если выбрать новое оно вообще не добавляется, если уже что-то было проставлено - стирает. (конкретно здесь некое подобие админки и проставляются права пользователя - USER или ADMIN, предполагается, что, когда заходишь в редактирование пользователя галка прав уже проставлена в зависимости от текущих прав). 
При этом, при уже проставленых правах - считывает и ставит чекбоксы верно.
Фрагмент шаблона, который ставит чекбоксы верно, но отправляет пустоту:

```
        <form th:action="@{/user}" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="username" th:value="${user.username}">
        <div th:each="role:${roles}">
        <label><input th:type="checkbox"
                   th:name="${role}"
                   th:value="${role}"
                   th:text="${role}"
                   th:field ="${user.roles}">    
  </label>
```

Были попробованы другие варианты, которые верно сохраняют в базу права, но при считывании чекбоксы или всегда не выбраны или всегда выбраны:

```
<div th:each="role:${roles}">
    <input th:type="checkbox"
           th:name="${role}"
           th:value="${role}"
           th:checked="${roles}"> //если убрать - ничего не выбрано 
    <label th:text="${role}" ></label>
</div>
<div th:each="role:${roles}">
    <label><input th:type="checkbox"
                  th:name="${role}"
                  th:value="${role}"
                  th:text="${role}"
                  th:checked="${roles}">//если убрать - ничего не выбрано 
    </label>
```

Как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо.

Ниже файлы шаблона(userEdit.html) и контроллера (UserController)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title >Edit user</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User edition </title>
</head>
<body>
User edition

 <form th:action="@{/user}" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="username" th:value="${user.username}">
<div th:each="role:${roles}">
    <label><input th:type="checkbox"
               th:name="${role}"
               th:value="${role}"
               th:text="${role}"
               th:field ="${user.roles}">
  </label>
</div>
     <input type="hidden" th:value="${user.id}" name="userId">
     <button type="submit">Save</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер:
    package org.studyproject.metagram.controller;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.studyproject.metagram.domain.Role;
import org.studyproject.metagram.domain.User;
import org.studyproject.metagram.repos.UserRepo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
//@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @GetMapping
    public String userList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userRepo.findAll());
        return "userList";
    }

    @GetMapping("{user}")
    public String userEditForm(@PathVariable User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());

        return "userEdit";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String userSave(
            @RequestParam String username,
            @RequestParam Map<String, String> form,
            @RequestParam("userId") User user
    ) {
        user.setUsername(username);

        Set<String> roles = Arrays.stream(Role.values())
                .map(Role::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        user.getRoles().clear();

        for (String key : form.keySet()) {
            if (roles.contains(key)) {
                user.getRoles().add(Role.valueOf(key));
            }
        }

        userRepo.save(user);

        return "redirect:/user";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение простое:

```
th:checked="${#lists.contains(user.roles, role)}" >
```